# How to insert dynamic input values into the database using codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have dynamic input data and i want to store Item name(Refer image:1)
[image]

data into the database in the same column like given in the database image (Refer image:2).
[image]

How do i do that in codeigniter?

I want to store dynamic input data of item name like given in the item_name column.

```
<?php 
 Class my_controller extends CI_controller{         
   public function my_method(){
    $data = array(
    'total_price' => $this->input->post('total_price'), //Total price of all item
    'item_name' => $this->input->post('item_name') //Dynamic input value of item name
);
$result = $this->my_model->inser_item($data);
}
 }
?>
```

```html
<div>
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>my_controller/my_method" method="post">
<input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name">
<input type="text" name="total_price" id="total_price">

<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post data not an images

Comment: Need a little more clarity on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks both for the reply..I have dynamic input for item name and a input for total price ..i want to store the data of item name in a same column..like in the image "Database" item_name column. check the image you'll understand.. @abhinav

Comment: Your code and your images look quite different. In the image, you are having multiple inputs while in the code it looks like you are having just one input.

Comment: Thanks..I got the answer .@abhinav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I get it correctly, if you want to insert the `item_name` values into a single table column, you could `implode()` it :

```
...
$data = array(
    'total_price' => $this->input->post('total_price'), //Total price of all item
    'item_name' => implode(',', $this->input->post('item_name')) //Dynamic input value of item name
);
...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Exactly what i was looking for.. @Hasta Dhana. I solved it already